# top-bar incorrectly claims I have unread messages

Tags: bug, top-bar

This, I see on the top-right on SO:

[image: Current Picture]

So it claims "You have unread inbox messages", but then there are no unread inbox messages, at least there is no red number indicating them.

---

I got it reproduced, with a further message. It seems that

1. I get alerted for a new message
2. I click on the inbox icon and the popup with the messages appears
3. When I now click on the most recent message, the corresponding page opens.
4. Now, in that page, the inbox has no longer a red number, but when I hover over it, I again get the situation described above.
5. When I now reload the page, the problem is gone.

And here it's now the other way round, I get a new message, I see a red number, but the text does not take this into account:

[image: Other picture]

Comment: Maybe, you had unread messages, read them, and the title didn't update? does refreshing page fix it?

Comment: @KevinB: Refreshing now helped - in the meantime, I got a ~ 6 days old message, (all within the same browser), now it seems fine, until the next message...

Comment: Interestingly while trying to reproduce this, I found that I'm actually not receiving some of the notifications. Specifically those from chat.

Comment: @TinyGiant: And this time, the hover-message did not change, only the red number appeared to indicate you rmessage.

Comment: Same here. Odd.

Comment: I was able to recreate this problem in Chrome. I got a notification, hovered, had the mentioned title, opened inbox, closed it, and the title was still the same.

Comment: @KevinB ahh so you have to hover it before opening it.